# dangling pointers java using arrays

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a dangling pointer using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976668/creating-a-dangling-pointer-using-java)

how to create dangling pointers in java but this time using arrays as memory allocators?

Comment: You already asked this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976668/creating-a-dangling-pointer-using-java  and the answer was no.

Comment: If this is your homework, then try to do some of it yourself and if you're stuck somewhere ask here, **but** make sure to tell us what you tried **and** where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

There can't be [dangling pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) in Java. The language is defined in a way that makes it impossible.

Object will only ever be removed by garbage collection when they are no longer reachable.

The closest you can get to a dangling pointer is a reference that holds `null` (i.e. doesn't point to any object). But that's still a defined value with defined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java uses a garbage collector, it's impossible to create a dangling pointer in Java. I guess if you misinterpret what a "dangling pointer" is, you could see the null pointers a newly created array (of a reference type) is filled with as "dangling pointers".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a dangling pointer or reference in Java [Creating a dangling pointer using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976668/creating-a-dangling-pointer-using-java)